# Combining has_many :through with polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails (5.2) app I have `User`, `Organization`, `Subscription`, and `Event`.

`User`s belong to an `Organization` and both `User`s and `Organization` may subscribe to an `Event`.

[image]

Now I need for a `User` get the associated events both through his personal subscription and the subscriptions belonging to his organization.

I'm trying to create the `subscribable` polymorphic association.

The `subscriptions` table has the following fields:

- id
- event_id
- subscribable_id
- subscribable_type

But now I'm stuck, Not sure how to set the associations between `User`, `Organization`, and `Subscription`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscribable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :subscriber,   polymorphic: true
end
```

Ths `User` should be at the same time `subscribable` and `subscriber` but I can't make it work.

How should I set the associations in the `User` model?

Comment: I think you are going good, just need to remove `belongs_to :subscriber,   polymorphic: true` and add `has_many` relation in both user and organization. Subscription will have `belongs_to :event` too.

Comment: `has_many :subscriptions` and 
`has_many :events, :through => :subscriptions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should do

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscribable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :event
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions, as: :subscribable
  has_many :events, through: :subscriptions
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions, as: :subscribable
  has_many :events, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :users
end
```

Now, If you want call *user's subscriptions and events*, then

```
@user.events
@user.subscriptions
```

If you want to call *subscriptions* and *events* of the *user's organization*, then

```
@user.organization.events
@user.organization.subscriptions
```

> The User should be at the same time subscribable and subscriber but I
>   can't make it work.

Not sure what you meant, but if want to get the subscribers of a subscription then add an association in the `Subscription` model like so

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscribable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :subscribers, source: :user
end
```

Now, `@subscription.subscribers` will give a list of users subscribed to that subscription.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.